# Unhandled: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created an azure devops pipeline which builds image from source code and pushes to docker . I created a service connection for that as shown below:

Service connection type
Docker Registry

using managed identity authentication

[image]

However when i run the pipeline job it is throwing this error

```
Unhandled: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: %s, status message: %s
```

The docker task is as follows:

```
task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push 
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRep)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

i have contributor rights so from az cli i can do the docker push to the acr but with
devops getting this error.

Can anyone help here? Thanks

Comment: Where are you running your pipeline?

Comment: i have created an organization and running there

Comment: In the microsoft-hosted runner? Is it supporting MSI?

Answer (score 2):

If you are choosing managed identity while creating service connection in azure devops, then you should use **azure devops self hosted agent** with docker installed. Please follow the below steps to setup configuration.

**Step 1:** Create windows VM in Azure and configure self-hosted agent in Azure devops using the link [self-hosted agent on windows machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops).

**Step 2:** Install Docker desktop on windows VM using this link [Docker desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/).

**Step 3:** Enable **system assigned managed identity in VM**  and  make note of **object id** for later use and add azure role assignments **ACRPush** and **ACRPull**.
[image]

[image]

**Step 4:** Create Service connection in Azure devops.
[image]

**Step 5:** create and run the pipeline as below.

```
pool: Default2  # self-hosted agents pool name
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'svc2-acr' #docker service connection (using managed-identity)
    repository: 'testimg'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
      latest
```

Run the pipeline and check for results.
[image]

[image]

**References:**
[Build and publish Docker images to Azure Container Registry using Mnagaed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/publish-to-acr?view=azure-devops&tabs=javascript,portal,msi)